# How to get 'to' field in firebase could messaging JSON?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can succesfully send Firebase cloud messages to my Android sample project. As [described in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/7592495), I apply step 2 and it works so far.

My JSON body:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/testTopic",
    "data": {
        "key1" : "val1",
        "key2" : true
     }
}
```

has a data field which I can access properly in my onMessageReceived() method:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String toVal = remoteMessage.getTo();
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
}
```

But the getTo() method gets null. 
**How can I access the 'to' field in my originating JSON?**

I was expecting to have `"/topics/testTopic"` in im variable **toVal**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`RemoteMessage.getFrom()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getFrom()):

> Get the sender of this message.
>
> This will be the sender ID or the topic for topic messages.